# Variable Javascript into datalayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-datalayer

with following code i'm trying to pass variable "textSelected" to datalayer.
For checking that works correctly i made an alert and works correctly on every option change. However not works into datalayer. Why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    jQuery(function($) {
      $('select#ddlV1').on('change', function() {
        var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
        var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();
        var textSelected   = optionSelected.text();
        //alert (textSelected);
        dataLayer.push({
          'event':'GAevent',
          'eventID':'13',
          'eventCategory':'filter_on_listing',
          'eventAction':'marca',
          'eventLabel': textSelected
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you initialize dataLayer? What output do you expect? how do you check if it works?

Comment: I check this in console https://ibb.co/260wQLt and about inizialization i did in this way https://ibb.co/rk6SWQN

Comment: Looks like you have initialized the dataLayer in a seperated `<script>` tag. Try init it in the same tag as your code

Comment: Ok thanks i tried but still variable is not replaced..